# Bitbucket on Docker: Cant access Marketplace

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Im trying to run Bitbucket in Docker at my company for production.
My machine is behind a proxy, which blocks almost everything, for security reasons. You know that you can authentificate with a proxy-user to access the www. I passed the user in the Dockerimage and the container is acutually able to connect with the www. But the Bitbucket-application is NOT. Everytime I start the server this coming up:

> com.atlassian.upm.pac.PacClientImpl Error when querying application info from MPAC: com.atlassian.marketplace.client.MpacException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to marketplace.atlassian.com:443 [marketplace.atlassian.com/52.2.89.223, marketplace.atlassian.com/34.239.16.84, marketplace.atlassian.com/34.205.61.250] failed: connect timed out

I tried to pass some JVM_OPTS via environmentvariables:

> `JVM_OPTS=" -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= -Dhttp.proxyUser=-Dhttp.proxyPassword=-Dhttps.proxyUser=-Dhttps.proxyPassword="`

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bitbucket-Server versions 5.0+, there is a "_start-webapp.sh" where you can add the the JVM arguements. There is a variable calls "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=".

In my case it didn't worked well, when I just copyed the new "_start-webapp.sh" in the Container, when the app was just unziped. You can easily add the a env-variable in your Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml like this:

```
ENV JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=" -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= -Dhttp.proxyUser=-Dhttp.proxyPassword=-Dhttps.proxyUser=-Dhttps.proxyPassword="
```